# diffculty choosing an item from a list view

Tags: java, android-layout, listview, android-studio

Hello I've built a list view that in its XML file have 2 layouts with background and 1 text view on each layout,I'm getting from the strings array text, And changing the text view,this is my code for the row I'm getting for for the list view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/purple"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/rl1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/purple"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/rl2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now my problem is when I'm trying to choose only one of the boxes on list view on item selected and doing a switch on the positions I'm getting the 2 boxes on the same position so it don't matter what what box I'm choosing, Iv'e try to give the linear layouts id and then use set on click listener on them with no successes,I'll appreciate and suggestions.

Comment: i think you want at time one view show other will not if you need that than you have to programmatically hide view which you not want and also visible view which you want to visible. this thing you have to do in your adapter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand.

Do you use this layout to create `ListView` items ?

If that is the case, the problem may be that when the `ListView` is refreshed, it inflates instances of this layout (in its default configuration, the components are in their default position). In order to preserve the changes, you will need to save each item's state and modify its layout every time the list is refreshed.

Comment: I'll try to explain I'm using this layout to create ListView items. then I'm inflating 5 rows and getting 10 boxes, so my first row is position 0  for example and it got 2 boxes now I'm trying to pick from these 2 boxes and i i cant use positions because its refer to both boxes as once, so my question is how do I choose only one of these boxes?

Comment: @BenShabat You can create a custom list adapter and add click listeners to both text views of an item.